# Can ServiceStack and Ormlite update multiple records like a SQL CASE statement can?

Tags: t-sql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

In this situation, there are multiple rows with the same device GUID because more than one user may use the same app on the device (but not simultaneously…unless they’re extraordinarily close). What this query does is get all the rows that share the same device GUID, then sets the InUse bit to true (1) if the UserId matches (3012). Any row within that set with a different user ID gets its InUse bit set to false (0). This avoids having to make more than one call to the server.

```
UPDATE Devices 
SET InUse = (CASE UserId WHEN 3012 
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
WHERE DevGuid = '94F74150-26B0-4396-982C-675A14A66FAD';
```

If there's a way to do this with ServiceStack/Ormlite I'd prefer to go that route because of the IOC advantages. But other considerations include making as few calls to the server as possible. Also, going "old school" with ADO.NET allows me to work the most fluidly with the SQL Server Geography and Geometry types. (I'm already a refugee from Microsoft's Azure Mobile Services because of its real-world limitations).

Comment: Did you got solution of updating multiple values from one query ?

Comment: No...and it was one reason I was unable to continue using ServiceStack.